# Jquery - multilevel Drop down menu ("vertical")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to build a drop down menu using the jquery using the click event not the hover event.
What i come up in coding is working appropriately is there any other short way to perform multilevel drop down menu

```js
  var initMenu = {
    show: function() {
      $('#left_dropbar ul ul').hide();
      $('#left_dropbar ul:first').show();
      $('#left_dropbar li a').click(function() {
        var checkClick = $(this);
        var checkElement = $(this).next();
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
          var ulCheck = checkClick.parent();
          ulCheck.find('ul').slideUp('normal');
          return false;
        }
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
          checkElement.slideDown('normal');
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    initMenu.show();
  });
```

```css
    /** css **/
    body {
      font: 12px/17px Arial, Tahoma, Sans-serif;
    }
    #left_dropbar {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #left_block .headerbar {
      background: url("arrowstop.gif") no-repeat scroll 8px 6px #606060;
      color: #FFF;
      font: bold 13px Verdana;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding: 7px 0 7px 10px;
    }
    #left_dropbar li {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 3px 0;
    }
    #left_dropbar li a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    #left_block {
      background: none;
      float: left;
      width: 225px;
    }
    #firstlevel {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #firstlevel a {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E9E9E9;
      color: #000;
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 5px 0 5px 8px;
    }
    ul li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    #left_dropbar ul {
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    ul,
    li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>New Document</title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus" />
  <meta name="Author" content="" />
  <meta name="Keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="Description" content="" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/left.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/left.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="left_block">
    <div class="headerbar">Search</div>
    <div id="left_dropbar" class="left_content">


      <!-- First level menu start here -->
      <ul id="firstlevel">
        <li><a href="#">Overview</a>
          <!-- Sub level 1 menu start here -->
          <ul class="subfirstlevel">
            <li><a href="#">Guidelines</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Visual Specifications</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Interactions</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Sub level 1 menu end here -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Table of Content</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Layout</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Required Screen Elements</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Layout</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Controls</a>
          <!-- Controls Sub level 1 menu start here -->
          <ul class="subfirstlevel">
            <li><a href="#">Buttons</a>
              <!-- Controls Sub level 2 menu start here -->
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Guidelines</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Visual Specifications</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Interactions</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Controls Sub level 2 menu end here -->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CheckBoxes</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Combo Boxes</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
          <!-- Controls Sub level 1 menu end here -->
        </li>


      </ul>
      <!-- First level menu end here -->

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question to me.

Comment: I am looking for the better approach

Comment: which is exactly what Code Review was created for. This is for more specific programming questions, ussually involving problems that need to be solved. Not a general "How can I do this better," that is what Code Review is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you had up only worked for me on the first link/submenu.  I would add

```
#left_dropbar ul ul{display: none;}
```

to your css and simplify your javascript to

```
function expandMenu(e){
    var sublist = $(e.target).next("ul");      
    if(sublist.length != 0){
        if(sublist.is(":visible")){
            sublist.slideUp('normal');
        }
        else{
            sublist.slideDown('normal');
        }
    }
    return false;    
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#left_dropbar ul:first').show();
    $('#left_dropbar li a').click(expandMenu);
});
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/post_erasmus/Jg9eW/1/) fiddle.